# Store just time

Tags: mongodb, datetime, time, momentjs

So I need to store times so I can check if another time is between them however the date is irrelevant so I'd rather not store that to minimize confusion. What's the best way to store a moment time '2:02am' in MongoDB?

Comment: It's not a good idea. As noted the smallest "variable string length" ( you can't have fixed string length in MongoDB ) takes 6-bytes ( 4 chars plus separator plus length byte ). A BSON Date is stored internally as a "4-byte integer" containing the whole date. And if you tried to make this numeric, then your might get away with "minutes in a day" at "2-bytes" being `1440` as a max value. But any further precision takes more than 2-bytes and therefore you may as well use the BSON Date, which only uses 4-bytes anyway. So think through the problem logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of an opinionated question, but using military time as a string is probably your best bet: `"02:02"` for 2:02 am and `"14:02"` for 2:02 pm.

You'll need to be careful to handle "rollover" correctly, where a time is between say `"23:00"` and `"01:00"` the next day, depending on your use case.

The other way to go is to convert the time into numeric minutes (0-1440) or seconds (0-86400) into the day, depending on required precision, which will result in smaller storage requirements and faster searches.

Comment: Not only opininated but honestly pretty irresponsible to suggest that storing a "string" and one of greater length than any possible numeric representation of the time would be an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: Making comparison way more expensive, too.

Comment: Fair enough, numeric option added.